# Automatically assign spring's bean name to prevent name conflicts?

Tags: spring

In a spring app , if two programmers develop two packages , annotating @Repository to the same class name , Spring will throw "IllegalStateException" :

> Annotation-specified bean name
>   'mybean' for bean class
>   [foobar.package1.mybean] conflicts
>   with existing, non-compatible bean
>   definition of same name and class
>   [foobar.package2.mybean]

One solution is to add extra value in the @Repository , such as `@Repository("package1.mybean")` and `@Repository("package2.mybean")` , but I am looking for a more efficient solution , that can automatically ease such situation . I hope the solution can achieve these goals :

1. Programmers could arbitrarily name their bean className in his package , regardless of name conflicting with other packages(programmers). So that programmer doesn't need to yell 'Hey , I am going to use bean name XXXXX , don't conflict with me'.
2. No manually XML bean name assign.
3. If the bean name can be automatically assigned to the class's full class name , that would be great.

Any ideas ? Thanks.
(Spring 3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Somewhere in your config, you've enabled classpath scanning, probably using

```
<context:component-scan>
```

You can specify a property called `name-generator`, which takes a bean that implements the `BeanNameGenerator` interface. Create your own implementation of that interface and provide a reference to it.

Comment: Here is my simple implementation of a package named bean name generator: public class PackageBeanNameGenerator implements BeanNameGenerator { public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) { String beanClassName = Introspector.decapitalize(definition.getBeanClassName()); logger.debug("Instantiating bean with name: " + beanClassName); return beanClassName; } }

Answer (score 6):

This is because it is using `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` which simply put **non-qualified name(class name)** as the bean name, then caused conflict.

Two steps to resolve this:

1、You can implement your own bean name generation strategy which use **fully-qualified name (package + class name)** like below

```
public class UniqueNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {
    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        //use fully-qualified name as beanName
        String beanName = definition.getBeanClassName();
        return beanName;
    }
}
```

2、Add `@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = UniqueNameGenerator.class)` to configuration or Boot class if you are using SpringBoot

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = UniqueNameGenerator.class)
public class Config {
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of Spring instead of writing your own implementation, you can just use `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` which is doing exactly the same thing.